# set a variable in django template file, and update it after iteration

Tags: django, python-3.x, templates

Trying to set variable in django template, and make a simple rule to update it after iteration. Here is my template:

```
{% for adv in advs %}
<div class="media-item big" style="top: 18%;left:{% cycle '304' '1078' %}px;">
    <div class="media-item__tags">
         <a href="#" class="tag">{{ adv.year }}</a>
         <a href="#" class="tag">{{ adv.payer}}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="media-item__content">
        <div class="media-item__background">
            <a href="project-spar.html" class="media-item-background__link"></a>
            <div class="media-item__canvas">
                <div class="media-item__canvas-background" style="background-image: url({{adv.image.url}})"></div>
            </div>
            <h2 class="topic white upcase fixed-size">{{ adv.name }}</h2>
            <a href="#" class="link regular width600-only">Смотреть проект</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In first div i need to make different 'left:' value. I want to make rule: after every iteration, value changes from base=304 to base+774 px. I tryed to do it somehow with {% cycle %} but it doesnt work for me, also tryed to set variables with {% with %} tag, but didnt find any information about how to update them.

Comment: What is the value of the `style` you get now?

Comment: first -  left:304, second: 1078, third should be 1078+774. I cant do it with the {% cycle %} cause could be a lot of objects

Comment: This is what you're getting now or what you want?

Comment: Right now i have 1st iteration: 304, second: 1078, third: 304, 4th: 1078. I need 1st: 304, second 1078, third: 1852, 4th: 2626 etc. I cant do all with %cycle% cause i probably will have 500+ objects, so i want to set variable, that will update after every iteration. Question is how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `style` by multiplying the current counter from `0...n` with 774 and add base value `304`. For this, you'll need a custom template tag.

Create a `templatetags` directory in your app. Add an empty `__init__.py` and `multiply_add.py`.

**multiply_add.py**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def mul_add(a, b, base_value):
    return (a * b) + base_value
```

**template.html**

```
{% load multiply_add %}

{% for adv in advs %}
<div class="media-item big" style="top: 18%;left:{% multiply_add forloop.counter0 774 304 %}px;">
    <div class="media-item__tags">
         <a href="#" class="tag">{{ adv.year }}</a>
         <a href="#" class="tag">{{ adv.payer}}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="media-item__content">
        <div class="media-item__background">
            <a href="project-spar.html" class="media-item-background__link"></a>
            <div class="media-item__canvas">
                <div class="media-item__canvas-background" style="background-image: url({{adv.image.url}})"></div>
            </div>
            <h2 class="topic white upcase fixed-size">{{ adv.name }}</h2>
            <a href="#" class="link regular width600-only">Смотреть проект</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: done. The only thing: in template should be {% mul_add forloop.counter0 774 304 %}. Then it works ;)