# how to update the value of a db field in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a variable called `status` in my models.py as following:

```
class message(models.Model):

    class Choices_status(models.TextChoices):
        unread = 'Unread', "Unread"
        processing = 'Processing', "Processing"
        obsolete = 'Obsolete', "Obsolete"
       

    status = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=Choices_status.choices, default=Choices_status.unread, blank=True)
```

It indicates the status of a message. I want to change the value of it to other choices of the `Choices_status`.

i.e. inside of a template that I am showing a list of `messages`, I want to change this variable's value to other choices if a message is selected and showed on a new page.

All I could find was working with `{% with %}` tag that is not suitable for my case.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I want to update the value of a field of the database from within a template. I'm not using Django forms and class views.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Django documentation about choice field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/) .

Your code should look like this:

```
class message(models.Model):
  UNREAD = 'Unread'
  PROCESSING= 'Processing'
  OBSOLETE= 'Obsolete'
  MY_CHOICES = [
        (UNREAD ,'Unread')
        (PROCESSING,'Processing')
        (OBSOLETE,'Obsolete')
  ]
  status = models.CharField(
    max_length=25,
    choices=MY_CHOICES,
    default=UNREAD,
    blank=True
  )
```

Comment: I don't get how it is supposed to help?!

Comment: Please don't post only a link as an answer. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and specifically "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: @Kemp thanks for the tip, but please answer my question :v

Comment: @Shahriar.M I edited the answer and added the code

Comment: I want to update the value of a field of the database (say `status` ) from within a template. please tell how to change the value ?

Comment: you can try registering your own tag in templates as explained <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711211/set-a-variable-in-django-template-file-and-update-it-after-iteration">here</a>